# Double P Trap Unvented Under Slab

Tags: slab, p-trap

My kitchen sink has 2 p-traps that are unvented. One p-trap is under the kitchen sink, and the second is under the slab.

What should I do? I am concerned about toxic sewage gas, not a slow drain. It is noisy, but draining fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: P-traps go to a main drain which is vented, usually though the roof.  Do you mean you do not have this vent?  Do you think there should be an air admittance valve near the p-trap?

Comment: There is no vent to the roof. It’s a kitchen sink in an island. I want to put an air admittance valve after the P-Trap directly under the sink, but there is another P-Trap directly under the slab.  I am concerned without a vent, the water is being siphoned out of the P-Trap, but there is also a double P-Trap.

Comment: If anything I would expect the AAV to make things better.